# Ant script for svn folder is not working

Tags: svn, ant

I am new to svn, I want to delete the folder inside the svn tag repository.

My ant script to do this as follows:

```
<target name="commit_delete" depends="delete">
        <svn javahl="false" svnkit="${svnkit}" username="${svnant.repository.user}" password="${svnant.repository.passwd}">
                        <commit message="conflicted file" dir="E:\SVN_NutansT\tags" />
                </svn>
    </target>
<target name="delete">
<svn>
<delete>
  <fileset dir="E:\SVN_NutansT\tags\2015_05_07_11_28_29_pa_Deploy" includes="**/org.junit*/**" />
</delete>
</svn>
</target>
```

This code was build successfully but not deleting the folder.What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is org.junit* the folder you want deleted? The includes of **/org.junit*/** will delete all files and folders inside of org.junit*, but not the folder itself.

Here is an example from https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true">
  <fileset dir="build" includes="**/*"/>
</delete>
```

It deletes all files and subdirectories of build, without build itself.

The manual has some other good examples as well.